# errors template instantiation and signed/unsigned mismatch c++, array

Tags: c++, arrays, signed

I am doing the following code in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;


template<class T>
void displayArray(T * items, unsigned start, unsigned end)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++)
    cout << items[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){

double Array[] = {103, 44, 211, 1, 102, 90, 20, 45, 3, 23, 10 };

displayArray(Array, 0, 10); 


return 0;
}
```

I know to display the elements in the array is not necessary to use template but I want to practice using it since I will implement it later with methods such as sorting. However I get the following error:

> note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void displayArray(T *,unsigned int,unsigned int)' being compiled
>
> ```
> with
>      [            
>          T=double
>      ]
> ```

I know how to use template with classes, but what am I missing here?

My other error is:

> warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch

which refers to the for loop, I know it has to do with my unsigned parameters and the fact that i is int but what would be correct to use then?

Comment: Unrelated to template.change to `unsigned int i`.

Comment: Here `for (int i = 0; i <= end; i++)` you compare an `signed int i` with an `unsigned int end`

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you worked perfectly!

Comment: @cwschmidt  thank you!

Comment: Btw, instead of `const T*, unsigned startIndex, unsigned endIndex`, it is more idiomatic to pass iterator (half open range): `const T*begin, const T* end` and so `displayArray(std::begin(Array), std::end(Array))`.

Comment: "`note`" isn't an error. It is shown after an actual error or warning to provide more information.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you very much

Comment: @interjay thank you!